# How to run two monitors on two diffrent nVidia cards?

Tags: nvidia

The problem I have is that the graphic cards are old and I cant install it correctly

```
lspci| grep vga

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation NV18 [GeForce4 MX 440 AGP 8x] (rev a2)
02:01.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation NV34 [GeForce FX 5500] (rev a1)
```

I think I need nvidia-173. The following packages have unmet dependencies and it won't let me install this.

Is this possible running 12.04?

Would like to run both.

Comment: Don't think it's going to work. The two cards are supported by two different nvidia drivers in Ubuntu, [nvidia-96](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/nvidia-96) and [nvidia-173](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/nvidia-173), and you won't be able to install both. Perhaps two fx5xxx card will work, not sure.

Comment: flagged as possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/21144

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get two monitors across two cards after some seriously frustrating brute force troubleshooting. 
 
 I Learned the following... 
1. Lightdm seems (Seems = not an official statement) to hate mixed cards (gnome, doubly so)
2. Gnome (Classic) would do weird things on me. 
3. Unity worked across two monitors when i ran [xinit] from CLI as root. and then started unity from terminal with [unity-panel &] 
At least I think thats the command I used... I started unity with &